# Why try_files go to location, even file exists?

Tags: nginx, configuration

My nginx is stupid(but I guess, really it's me :)).

Watch this:

```
server {
    server_name myproject.dev;
    listen 127.0.100.1:80;

    error_log /srv/resourses/error.log;
    access_log /srv/resourses/access.log;


    location / {
        root /srv/resources/static;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @node;
    }

    location /static {
        root /srv/resourses;
    }

    location @node {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080$uri?$query_string;
    }
}
```

I want to serve static files and proxy dynamic requests to nodejs. Try_files looking for the files and if file dosn't exists - go to node. Simple. But on my case, try_files don't stop on founded file and going forward to backend. So I get wrong file as response. What's going on?

Comment: Config correct. `http://myproject.dev/file.txt` return `/srv/resources/static/file.txt` if this file exists.

Comment: Is the spelling of `resourses` and `resources` just a typo in the question?